# Update the last 360 rows of a table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 360 rows at the end of the table where I need to change the date from 2013-08-26 to 9999-12-31. I tried this query but got a syntax error.

```
UPDATE xxx_score
SET xxx_date_to = 9999-12-31
WHERE xxx_date_to = 2013-08-26
ORDER BY `xxx_score`.`xxx_id` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 360
```

but got

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 360' at line 5

Any help please in where I am going wrong.

Comment: You need single-quotes around your dates. As it stands, those are mathematical expressions (9999 minus 12 minus 31)

Comment: MySQL likes `20130826` or `'2013-08-26'` or `DATE '2013-08-26'` (the latter being the ANSI standard), but when it sees `2013-08-26` it treats it as a math expression: 2013 minus 8 minus 6.

Comment: @EdGibbs: `LIMIT` *should* work with updates... [spec says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) "The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated."

Comment: Thanks @Mark! I just looked at the test statement I tried and I had messed that up. Fixed it and `LIMIT` worked like a charm. I'll update my comment.

Comment: @EdGibbs I used the quotes around the date and still the same syntax error.

Comment: MatthewUnderwood: see the answer from @mata - it's the correct one. I tried `LIMIT 0, 360` and got the syntax error but when I tried `LIMIT 360` it worked. Also make sure you're quoting both dates - your comment says "the date" and there are two dates, so just making sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing **`LIMIT 0, 360`** to **`LIMIT 360`**.
You can use only row count after LIMIT in UPDATE: [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 4):

Dates should be enclosed in quotes as described here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html

`ORDER BY AND LIMIT` are OK, as long as you don't `JOIN`.